# How to seed lodash random number generator?

Tags: javascript, typescript, random, lodash

How can I seed the lodash rng so that the random choices for the shuffle function are reproducible?

E.g.

```
import _ from 'lodash'

console.log(_.shuffle([1,2,3,4]))
```

Run #1 output: `[1,3,4,2]`

Run #2 output: `[3,2,1,4]`

Run #3 output: `[4,1,2,3]`

The result is always different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`lodash`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash) uses its own `Math.random` under the hood, but it is independent from the global `Math.random`, so using a library like [`seedrandom`](https://github.com/davidbau/seedrandom) to make `Math.random` seedable does not work.

Instead, we have to make use of `lodash`'s `runInContext()` function which uses the current global state instead of using it's own hidden-away version. Combining this with a seedable rng like `seedrandom` we can use the following to get a seeded version of `lodash`:

```js
import _lodash from 'lodash'
import seedrandom from 'seedrandom'

// create a new lodash instance with the given seed
export const seedLodash = (seed: number | string) => {
    // take a snapshot of the current Math.random() fn
    const orig = Math.random
    // replace Math.random with the seeded random
    seedrandom(seed, { global: true })
    // runInContext() creates a new lodash instance using the seeded Math.random()
    // the context is a snapshot of the state of the global javascript environment, i.e. Math.random() updated to the seedrandom instance
    const lodash = _lodash.runInContext()
    // restore the original Math.random() fn
    Math.random = orig
    // return the lodash instance with the seeded Math.random()
    return lodash
}
```

This creates an rng which replaces `Math.random`, makes a new `lodash` instance referencing the modified `Math.random`, then replaces `Math.random` with the original unmodified (i.e. unseeded) version.

If you want to seed **both** `lodash` and `Math.random` simply add these two lines at the top of your code:

```
import _lodash from 'lodash'
import seedrandom from 'seedrandom'

seedrandom(seed, { global: true });
const _ = _lodash.runInContext();
// use lodash and Math.random as normal...
```